# why php rand() function gives some time empty?

Tags: php, arrays, random

Hello When I try to use `rand()` function than it's give sometime empty like

```
// I want random value between 0-5000 , want 500 random value
 for ($i=0; $i < 500; $i++) { 
    $randNo = rand(0, 5000);

    if (in_array($randNo, $randArray)) {
        $randNo = InfiniteLoop($randArray ,$length_sec);
    }
    array_push($randArray,$randNo);
}
sort($randArray);
```

After that i print that array give some empty value.

```
//output
Array ( [0] =>  [1] => 523 [2] => 824 [3] ....so on )
```

Comment: What does your `InfiniteLoop()` function do? Right now only this function could be the source of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 500 *distinct* random numbers between 0 and 5000, then you should probably use `shuffle()` and `array_slice()`:

```
$allNumbers = range(0, 5000);

shuffle($allNumbers);

$randomNumbers = array_slice($allNumbers, 0, 500);
```

Comment: Very cool alternative solution for OP. I think even better then his current one. And if he don't show us his code to show OP the error. I think this is the answer here

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your 'InfiniteLoop' function, it is overwritting the results of rand()

Comment: This is a comment not a answer and there is already a comment for this!

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$allNumbers = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $allNumbers[] = $i;
}

uniqid($allNumbers);
```